# Download a template from Tableauserverclient and upload it in a Blob Storage with Azure functions Python

Tags: python, download, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, tableau-api

So I have been trying for the past weeks to get templates from a project in tableau and upload them into my blob storage. Since I don't want to do that manually, I guessed that Azure functions would help me automate this.
I used this code snippet to download all the templates from Tableau:

```
# download workbook
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
            ...
   workbook_file = server.workbooks.download(template_workbook_id, include_extract=False)
   blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=template_workbook.name)
   blob_client.upload_blob(workbook_file, overwrite=True)
   logging.info("Workbook downloaded and saved to Blob Storage")
```

This works perfectly fine localy but unfortunately not in azure functions since its read only. The error appears in "server.workbooks.download".
Tried to work with temp files but it wasn't much of a help.

Does anyone have any ideas? Would be awesome.

Tried to leave the filepath from server.worbooks.download()
Tried temp files
And tried to download the Templates within the azure function.